# CK Editor media plugin file upload error

Tags: drupal-7, ckeditor, drupal-modules

I'm trying to upload a file using the CK editor media plugin, but it throws 500 internal server error in the url (/media/browser?render=media-popup&plugins=undefined). Also error with drupal media js settings
this.contentWindow.Drupal.media is undefined.

I search through the internet and it seems there is some issue with Drupal 7 media module. Your help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have the Media Upload installed and configured to work with your WYSIWYG editor? It should work as long as you have all of those things in place. Here is a great reference to help make sure you have everything setup the way you need.

https://www.drupal.org/node/1882314

Answer (score 1):

This blog can help you to find solution..http://www.ziuby.com/configure-media-drupal-upload-images/

Comment: Please quote the most relevant part of the link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. See [How do I write a good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).